# Subset the data based on an equation in R

Tags: r

In my very large data frame, I need to find the depth at which par = 1% of the maximum par at each station. I can find this depth using:

```
 Station <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7,7,8, 8, 8, 9, 9,9)
 Depth <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3)
 Value <- c(5, 8, 3, 2, 6, 8, 3, 6, 3, 8, 3, 5, 7, 2, 6, 9, 1, 3, 456, 321, 2, 5, 7, 4, 2, 6, 8)
 par <- c(100, 1, 0.05, 300, 3, 0.3, 250, 2, 0.2, 100, 1, 0.05, 300, 3, 0.3, 250, 2, 0.2,100, 1, 0.05, 300, 3, 0.3, 250, 2, 0.2)

 df <- data.frame(Station, Depth, Value, par)
 df

  miss <- function(x) ifelse(is.finite(x),x,NA)
  d.depths <- df %>%
  group_by(Station) %>%
  summarize(
  depth=miss(min(Depth[par <= 0.1*max(par, na.rm=TRUE)], Inf, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

This works.

But I need to retain all the information above this depth (i.e., where par is between 1 - 100%) and discard all the information below this depth (where par is <1%). I tried to subset, but I get an error of

> Error in subset.data.frame(df, miss(min(Depth[par <= 0.1 * max(par, na.rm = TRUE)],  : 
> 'subset' must be logical

```
depth= subset (df, miss(min(Depth[par <= 0.1*max(par, na.rm=TRUE)], Inf, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Can I not subset using this equation? I can do this manually, but my dataset has over 50,000 entries, so it takes a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can join `d.depths` with `df` and keep the depth value which is above 1% of max value.

```
library(dplyr)

d.depths %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'Station') %>%
  filter(Depth >= depth)
```

Comment: thank you! My data is every 2m. This mostly works but I seem to miss the 'final' depth. For example if depth at which par is 1% is 122m, then using the filter I get from 0 - 120. and if the depth is 74m, then using the filter I get 0-72m. I tried changing >= to == but then my file saves blanks... why does it omit the last one?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
par<-tapply(df$par,df$Station,max)
max_par<-par[df$Station]
df[df$par>=0.01*max_par,]

#   Station Depth Value par
#1        1     1     5 100
#2        1     2     8   1
#4        2     1     2 300
#5        2     2     6   3
#7        3     1     3 250
#10       4     1     8 100
#11       4     2     3   1
#13       5     1     7 300
#14       5     2     2   3
#16       6     1     9 250
#19       7     1   456 100
#20       7     2   321   1
#22       8     1     5 300
#23       8     2     7   3
#25       9     1     2 250
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try `mutate()` instead of `summarize()`? Then, filter out the rows with `par < 1`.

```
miss <- function(x) ifelse(is.finite(x),x,NA)
d.depths <- df %>% 
  group_by(Station) %>%
  mutate(
    depth=miss(min(Depth[par <= 0.1*max(par, na.rm=TRUE)], Inf, na.rm=TRUE))
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(par >= 1)

d.depths

# # A tibble: 18 x 5
#    Station Depth Value   par depth
#      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1       1     1     5   100     2
#  2       1     2     8     1     2
#  3       2     1     2   300     2
#  4       2     2     6     3     2
#  5       3     1     3   250     2
#  6       3     2     6     2     2
#  7       4     1     8   100     2
#  8       4     2     3     1     2
#  9       5     1     7   300     2
# 10       5     2     2     3     2
# 11       6     1     9   250     2
# 12       6     2     1     2     2
# 13       7     1   456   100     2
# 14       7     2   321     1     2
# 15       8     1     5   300     2
# 16       8     2     7     3     2
# 17       9     1     2   250     2
# 18       9     2     6     2     2
```